# PDO NOT Showing Results

Tags: php, pdo

this is my first Q.

I cant show the RESULT from $row['id'] ['name'] ['level']
IT only shows
ID:
NAME:
LEVEL:

But the results doest appear

Ive tryed adding PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to the FETCH() but it says 1 parameter given expected 0

```
require_once 'connection.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$stmt = $cnx->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo "Id: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";
echo "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Level: " . $row['level'] . "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: *"I cant show the results from $row['id'] ['name'] ['level'] The echo "id:" appears but not the result from mysql"* - You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: Can we see connection.php ?

Comment: You sure you're using PDO to connect with here? and not mysqli_?

Comment: Fred -ii-  
It only appears the ID:   but not the resutl that comes from de database that is the id number the member name and the member level

Sofiene DJEBALI
    <?php
    $cnx = @mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'cocstats' );
    if( ! $cnx ){
 header("Location: offline.php" );
    }
   ?>

Comment: @Fred-ii- I *think* he means that `echo "Id: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";` outputs **Id: <br>** - e.g. everything's output bar the record from the database; time for your almost famous *turn on error reporting* comment I feel.

Comment: @CD001 I don't bother with error reporting stuff anymore. Not after being bombed about it that I post useless comments about that. Just the generic "check for errors" ;--)

Comment: Yes its a school asignment i need PDO

Comment: This is what is shown
Id:
Name:
Level: 

And a i need for example
Id: 01
Name: Pocho
Level: Newbie

Comment: u_mulder 
It gaves me:  111111   (i have 6 members)

Comment: ^ that looks rather like the expected output from `mysqli::fetch()` (i.e. `true` x 6) as does the fact that you get the error `1 parameter given expected 0` ... are you sure you're using PDO?

Comment: [See this, 10+ mins ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350305/pdo-not-showing-results?noredirect=1#comment62216646_37350305) you never replied to that. So now I closed the question. Nor to another person who asked to see the connection codes.

Comment: I didnt saw that answer, as i told you all this was my first question and first time in this page looking for help

Comment: – Fred -ii- 
The answer was in the connection.php 

I need a try and a new PDO statement...

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `mysqli` api, then it's a bit complicated to use `fetch`:

```
$stmt = $cnx->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

// first you need to bind result to variables:
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $level)
// also make sure that you bind the SAME number 
// of variables as number of fields selected in a query

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Id: " . $id . "<br>";
    echo "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
    echo "Level: " . $level . "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: there was an answer that is now deleted and was probably right all along. Again... if that's the case, I'm closing this as a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php - Edit: I closed it.